# Colored coins implementation in Python

Tags: colored-coins

Is there any implementation of [this Colored Coins Protocol](https://github.com/Colored-Coins/Colored-Coins-Protocol-Specification) in Python?

I have found colored coins implementations in Python but, as far I as understand, they implement different protocol specifications (for instance [Chromaway's ngcccbase](https://github.com/chromaway/ngcccbase) or [Open Assets](https://github.com/OpenAssets/openassets)).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't any, unfortunately.

Rolling your own shouldn't be that difficult - I'd suggest using [CoinSpark's OP_RETURN library](https://github.com/coinspark/python-OP_RETURN) as a starting point. All the best!